# Multidimensional Arrays php from ics iCalendar

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I don't understand this array, I'm not able to echo out all the info in the DESCRIPTION only the first line. When I view the source code in the browser the array looks like this:

```
[198] => Array
(
[BEGIN] => VEVENT
[UID] => 20160304T065641CST-85574UpOPJnnnnn
[DTSTAMP] => 20160304T125641Z
[DESCRIPTION] => Be a part of the greater good for Bakersfield by attending this
[  green event! This expo showcases recycling and renewable energy businesse] =>
[ s and services throughout Kern County with nearly 40 vendors present to gi] =>
[DTSTART] => 20160423T080000
[DTEND] => 20160423T130000
[LOCATION] => Yokuts Park
[SUMMARY] => Greater Bakersfield Green Expo
[END] => VEVENT
)
```

The DESCRIPTION has three lines.

Then I run my little php code here:

```
$arrlength = count($stuff); 
for ($row = 0; $row <  $arrlength; $row++) {
echo "<p><b>Row number $row</b></p>";
echo "<ul>";
echo "<li>".$stuff[$row]['DESCRIPTION']."</li>";
echo "<li>".$stuff[$row]['DTSTART']."</li>";
echo "<li>".$stuff[$row]['DTEND']."</li>";
echo "<li>".$stuff[$row]['LOCATION']."</li>";
echo "<li>".$stuff[$row]['SUMMARY']."</li>";
echo "</ul>";
 }
```

And the output looks like this:

Row number 198

- Be a part of the greater good for Bakersfield by attending this
- 20160423T080000
- 20160423T130000
- Yokuts Park
- Greater Bakersfield Green Expo

Why is it only showing the first line on the DESCRIPTION and how do I make it echo the whole DESCRIPTION?

Comment: Because deacription contain only first line ur next line is index in your array thats reason u get only first line could u show ur code how's made this array?

Comment: I copied this guys ics parser [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757061/which-ics-parser-written-in-php-is-good) maybe I can tweak it so it doesnt make the array like that. I opened up the ics file and the description is on a bunch of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use foreach?

Guess your highest Array is called $stuff.

```
foreach($stuff as $stuffItem) {
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>'.$stuffItem[DESCRIPTION].'</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$stuffItem[DTSTART].'</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$stuffItem[DTEND].'</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$stuffItem[LOCATION].'</li>';
    echo '<li>'.$stuffItem[SUMMARY].'</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Imagine that you have a big array wich is having a lot of small arrays in it.
For my opinion best way to get a overview about your array is using:

```
echo "<pre>$yourArray</pre>";
```